# Is there an incompatibility between the packages breqn and subcaption

Tags: incompatibility, subcaption, breqn

When I try to typeset with both the packages [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) and [`breqn`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn), I get the following error:

> ! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly(caption) in compatibility mode.See the caption package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \begin{document}

However, if I deactivate either package, the document can typeset.

My preamble is as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\includeonly{intro}
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{breqn}

\listfiles

\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{%
 convert #1 \OutputFile
}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.gif}


\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\vectornorm}[1]{\left|\left|#1\right|\right|}
\newcommand{\pic}[5]{
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth]{#1} 
\caption[#3]{#4}
\label{#5}
\end{figure}
}

\title{\textbf{report\newline}}
\author{
\begin{tabular}{l c r}
First Middle Surname
\end{tabular}
}
\date{\today}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\begin{dmath}
x=5
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

Let me know if you wanna see file listing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug which has been fixed.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, for a reason I don't understand yet the combination of `float` and `breqn` package is incompatible to the `(sub)caption` package:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

will issue the warning

```
Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
```

which is obviously rubbish since the `caption` package should be aware about the redefinition of `\caption` done by the `float` package.

As a workaround one can save and restore the definition of `\caption` when loading the `float` package:

```
\let\captionORI\caption
\usepackage{float}
\let\caption\captionORI
```

As long as the `caption` package is used this should not make any harm (but outsmart the compatibility test of the `caption` package) since the `caption` package will redefine `\caption` anyway later on.

I will do further examination on week-end and report.

**The murder is out (2012-08-25):**

The `breqn` package redefines the LaTeX kernel macro `\@ifstar` in a way which is incompatible to at least one macro defined by the `caption` package. Since this macro will be used for the compatibility test this test could fail even if no incompatibility is actually present. I'll fix that in the next release of the `caption` package.

**Update (2013/01/09):**

The next release 3.3 of the `caption` package is out where this bug was fixed. Thanks for your patience.